# SPA login with MVC Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, angularjs, web-applications, single-page-application

Im started to play around with angular.js and Web API. right now i am trying to create a login functionallity. But i ran into a security question.

In my Account controller i have a method Login which logs user in if he exsists in db, and return empty account else.

```
        public Account Login(string loginName, string password)
    {
        var emptyAccount = new Account();
        password = Secure(password);

        var account = db.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Password == password && c.LoginName == loginName);

        if (account == null)
        {
            return emptyAccount;
        }

        account.Password = "";

        return account;
    }
```

Are there anyway to make this smarter with web API? because anyone will have access to route like ControllerName/Action/LoginName/Password.

Comment: Define "smarter"? What are the actual problems you're encountering, and how would you like to make your code smarter so those problems won't occur?

Comment: i think i have to rephrase the question. Is it the right way to create login in SPA trough Web API?

Comment: In that case, you might just want to make it a POST method. Is that what you mean?